# is there no floating point error on a / b == ka / kb?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Here is my simple code.

```
int num1, num2;
cin >> num1 >> num2;

int num3, num4;
cin >> num3 >> num4;

double result1 = static_cast<double>(num1) / num2;
double result2 = static_cast<double>(num3) / num4;

cout.setf(ios::boolalpha);
cout << (result1 == result2) << endl;
```

Input:

```
1 3
2 6
```

Output:

```
true
```

So I want to know that

```
static_cast<double>(a) / b == static_cast<double>(k * a) / (k * b)
```

is always true?

if not,

```
int num1, num2;
cin >> num1 >> num2;

int num3, num4;
cin >> num3 >> num4;

int gcd1 = gcd(num1, num2);
int gcd2 = gcd(num3, num4);

double result1 = static_cast<double>(num1 / gcd1) / (num2 / gcd1);
double result2 = static_cast<double>(num3 / gcd2) / (num4 / gcd2);

cout.setf(ios::boolalpha);
cout << (result1 == result2) << endl;
```

is always print `true` on input `a`, `b`, `k * a`, `k * b` to num1, num2, num3, num4?

Comment: I bet compiler is optimizing it out

Comment: @P__J__: No, as the numbers are input from stdin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming IEEE-754 binary floating-point arithmetic is used with the round-to-nearest-ties-to-even rule, the comparison is true except in the cases below.

Given `int` `num1`, `num2`, `num3`, and `num4` where `num3` = *k* • `num1` and `num4` = *k* • `num2` for some real number *k*, there are the following situations where `static_cast<double>(num1) / num2 == static_cast<double>(num3) / num4` may evaluate to false:

- `num3` and `num4` are both zero, either because `num1` and `num2` are zero or because *k* is zero. Then `static_cast<double>(num3) / num4` evaluates to a NaN, and a NaN never compares equal to anything, not even to the same NaN.
- `num2` is zero but `num1` is not and *k* is negative. Then `static_cast<double>(num1) / num2` evaluates to +∞ or −∞ according to whether `num1` is positive or negative, while `static_cast<double>(num3) / num4` evaluates to the opposite, −∞ or +∞ respectively, so the comparison evaluates to false.
- When `int`, excluding the sign bit, is wider than the significand of `double`, the quotients may differ due to different roundings in the conversion to `double`. For example, `int` may be 64 bits while `double` has a 53-bit significand. Suppose `num1` is 2<sup>53</sup>+1, `num2` is 1, and *k* is 3, so `num3` is 2<sup>54</sup>+2<sup>53</sup>+2+1 and `num4` is 3. Then, due to rounding, `static_cast<double>(num1)` produces 2<sup>53</sup>, `static_cast<double>(num3)` produces 2<sup>54</sup>+2<sup>53</sup>+4, and the divisions produce 2<sup>53</sup> and 2<sup>53</sup>+2, which are not equal.
- In cases where *k* • `num1` or *k* • `num2` overflows the `int` type, the comparison may evaluate to false.

Other than in the cases above, the conversions to `double` are exact, and the quotients are mathematically defined (do not have zero divisors) and are equal. In these cases, the rounding rule necessitates that the two divisions produce the same result, so the comparison evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get different answers; even when there are no `NaN`/`Infinity` etc. values are around. See Eric's fantastic answer as usual for the details. Here's a concrete counter-example to illustrate:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int32_t k = 1097303040;
    int32_t a = 536913409;
    int32_t b = 2097152;

    double  lhs = static_cast<double>(a)   / b;
    double  rhs = static_cast<double>(k*a) / (k*b);

    printf ("k    = %d\n", k);
    printf ("a    = %d\n", a);
    printf ("b    = %d\n", b);
    printf ("lhs  = %f\n", lhs);
    printf ("rhs  = %f\n", rhs);
    printf ("equal: %d\n", lhs == rhs);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, this program produces:

```
k    = 1097303040
a    = 536913409
b    = 2097152
lhs  = 256.020264
rhs  = -0.757798
equal: 0
```

Note that the results are not only not equal, they even have different signs!

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the nowadays usual implementation:

- IEEE-754 arithmetic
- `int` is 32-bit
- `double` is 64-bit binary float

With these, both are always true, because:

- `int` can be converted to `double` without any precision loss.
- IEEE-754 mandates that division should give the best possible result, correctly rounded. So both divisions must return the same value, there is no way that the comparison returns `false`.

---

Note, that this is only true, if your program doesn't contain Undefined Behavior. This can happen, for example, if your program contains division by zero. In this case, your comparison may result in false. Or a system exception is generated (so the comparison won't be executed at all).

Comment: The comparison evaluates to false if all the inputs are zero, as the divisions then produce NaNs, which never compare as equal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Division by zero is UB, so I didn't consider this case.

Comment: If the behavior is not defined by the C++ standard, that means the standard permits the comparison to evaluate to false, and hence the case ought to be listed as a possibility for the comparison to evaluate to false.

Comment: "both divisions must return the same value" is not true.  The multiplications might cause loss of precision, underflow, or overflow.

Comment: @geza Even though accepted, this answer is incorrect; and thus should be modified to reflect the analysis Eric provided. Otherwise, it's not the serving stack-overflow community.

Comment: @LeventErkok: I disagree. When a program contains UB, anything can happen. It is unnecessary to mention this every single time. Btw., your answer contains UB as well (signed overflow is UB). Besides (I'm sure that Eric knows this), 0/0 can generate an exception, instead of resulting in NaN.

Comment: The OP's question is not about UB's or anything else. She/he simply asks `is this equality test always true`. And the answer to that is a resounding no.

Comment: @LeventErkok: Yes, I see your point. But, if division by zero happens, that equality test may not be executed at all. I'll add this info into my answer.

Comment: @geza Thanks; that's more helpful to the community. The most likely way this will fail in practice is of course due to overflow, not due to division by zero. But the point stands.

Comment: @LeventErkok: Unfortunately, we don't know of the type of `k`. And even, maybe there's no `k` at all, OP just phrased the question this way. I answered this question in a way, that "what if we provide input numbers to the first code snippet in a way that `num3=num1*k` and `num4=num2*k`". So there is no `k`, but the input numbers has this special property.

Comment: There are two problems with “When a program contains UB, anything can happen. it is unnecessary to mention this every single time.” First, a person has asked a question. This indicates they are lacking some information, and that quite possibly includes not knowing what the specification conditions for undefined behavior are. A complete answer has to specify these conditions.…

Comment: … Second, we should not design code in a model where we always have defined behavior. When somebody asks “Is X always true?”, think of it in terms of “Will this car ever crash?” We should not give an answer assuming only defined behavior. If there is something in the code that could make X true, which could result in a car crashing and humans dying, we should say so. The answer **in fact** is no, X is not always true, and a correct answer has to say no. Correct engineering **requires** that.